# Why does this differentation output correct result?

Tags: calculus

I noticed something funny. If you differentiate $x^x$ treating the exponent as a constant, you get $xx^{x-1}=x^x$. If you treat the base as a constant, you get $x^x
\ln{x}$. If you add these two bizzare and incorrect derivatives of $x^x$, you get $x^x(1+\ln{x})$, which is **correct**!

Is it merely a weird and funny coincidence or is it a part of a deeper result?

(I'm checking it for $(x^x)^x$, but it will take a while :) )

Comment: [This website](http://www.analyzemath.com/calculus/Differentiation/first_derivative.html) says: Note that the function defined by $y = x^x$ is neither a power function of the form $x^k$ nor an exponential function of the form $b^x$ etc...

Comment: I know that! That's why I find this result funny, you apply incorrect method twice to get a correct result

Answer (score 6):

This is a general phenomenon. In this case
$$x^x=f(x,x)$$
where
$$f(u,v)=u^v.$$
By the chain rule,
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^x)=\frac d{dx}f(x,x)=f_1(x,x)+f_2(x,x)$$
where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the partial derivatives of $f$.
In this case
$$f_1(u,v)=v u^{v-1}$$
(considering $v$ as constant) and
$$f_2(u,v)=(\ln u) u^v$$
(considering $u$ as constant). So $f_1(x,x)=x^x$ and $f_2(x,x)=(\ln x)x^x$.

Comment: That looks like it generalises, allowing calculation of $\frac{d}{dx}(x\uparrow\uparrow n)$, ($n\in\Bbb N$), right?